# Check Heroku incoming and outgoing traffic

Tags: heroku, bandwidth

Is there any way to check how many gigabytes of traffic an heroku application has consumed?

Answer (score 6):

You could write a log parser to calculate the bandwidth used. Here is an example of the router log message

```
2013-03-27T04:02:21+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ 
host=somehost.herokuapp.com fwd="1.1.1.1" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms 
service=35ms status=200 bytes=49
```

parse for each router line with a `"bytes="` section and add up the bytes.

Comment: Thanks! I have done a simple script which I use on PaperTrailApp files containing Heroku logs: https://github.com/jsarenik/heroku-traffic